# Existe desvantagem em ter um número alto de Activities? Qual é a alternativa?

Tags: android

Sou iniciante no desenvolvimento Android e preciso criar um projeto com aproximadamente 120 telas. É correto usar 120 Activities?  Qual o custo disso? Há uma forma mais eficiente para este caso?

Comment: Marcelo, seja bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Forneça mais detalhes a respeito das telas que deseja criar, pois do jeito que está a pergunta está muito genérica. O que elas irão conter? Existe algum padrão que se repete nelas e que poderia levar a um reaproveitamento de código?

Comment: A sua aplicação terá mesmo120 actividades(interacções diferentes/coisas diferentes) que o usuário pode fazer?

Comment: nossa, acho que nunca vi uma aplicação com tantas telas assim

Answer (score 0):

Use fragments é o que a google recomenda, quando você cria muitas activities termina recriando views e códigos desnecessários.

Sobre fragments você pode ler [aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/desenvolvimento-android-reusando-componentes-com-a-api-de-fragmentos/29470) e [aqui](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/components/fragments.html)